# Tomcat 7 EL recognizing Method as Property

Tags: jsf-2, el, tomcat7

I'm trying to run an existing application on Tomcat 7.0.28 using JSF 2.1.10

I have the following bean:

```
@Named
@Dependent
public class FormatterBean
{
   public String replaceNewLineWithBrTag(String s)   
   {
      return Formatter.replaceNewLineWithBrTag(s);
   }

   public String leftJustifyWithZeros(String string, Integer zeroTotal)
    {
        return Formatter.leftJustifyWithZeros(string, zeroTotal);
    }
}
```

When I do something like this

```
<p:tooltip for="visualizar" value="#{formatterBean.replaceNewLineWithBrTag(adiantamento.observacao)}" />
```

I get the following error:

> /page/rdv/adiantamento.xhtml @87,117
>   value="#{formatterBean.replaceNewLineWithBrTag(adiantamento.observacao)}":
>   Property 'replaceNewLineWithBrTag' not found on type
>   br.com.spdata.util.FormatterBean

Some details:

1. Same code works fine on Glassfish 3.1.2
2. The method leftJustifyWithZeros works fine

Any ideias?

Thanks,
Phillip

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is whether your `web.xml` is declared as using the Servlet 3.0 spec, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
>
...
```

Comment: It is. Its strange because the leftJustifyWithZeros method works fine. If I change the replaceNewLineWithBrTag method signature and add another parameter it works.

Comment: I think this might be a Tomcat issue. Isn't there any other parameter like the -Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO that I need to set?